# How to use BeautifulSoup to scrape a webpage url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I get started with web scraping and I would like to get the URLs from certain page provided below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

page = "http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/fore_lt/2-_beds/any_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/57.610107,-65.170899,15.707662,-128.452149_rect/3_zm/"    

response = requests.get(page)
soup = Soup(response.text)
```

Now, I have all the info of the page in the soup content and I would like to get URLs of all the homes provided in the image 
    [image]

When, I INSPECT any of the videos of the home, the chrome opens this DOM element in the image:

[image]

How would I get the link inside the `<a href="">` tag using the `soup`? I think the parent is `<div id = "lis-results">`, but, I need a way to navigate to the element. Actually, I need all the URLs (391,479) of in a text file.

Zillow has an API and also, Python wrapper for the convenience of this kind of data job and I'm looking the code now. All I need to get is the URLs for the FOR SALE -> Foreclosures and POTENTIAL LISTING -> Foreclosed and Pre-foreclosed informations.

Comment: You should really look into using the [Zillow data API](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm), there is a [Python wrapper](https://github.com/hanneshapke/pyzillow), by the way.

Comment: This is really helpful, though I need to learn how to use the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the request you send  doesn't get the URLs. In fact, if I look at the response (using e.g. jupyter)  I  get:
[image: Missing the important part]

**I would suggest a different strategy**: these kind of websites often communicate via json files.

From the  `Network` tab of `Web Developer` in Firefox you can find the URL to request the json file:

[image: Firefox Network Tab]

Now, with this file you can get all the information needed.

```
import json
page = "http://www.zillow.com/search/GetResults.htm?spt=homes&status=110001&lt=001000&ht=111111&pr=,&mp=,&bd=2%2C&ba=0%2C&sf=,&lot=,&yr=,&pho=0&pets=0&parking=0&laundry=0&income-restricted=0&pnd=0&red=0&zso=0&days=any&ds=all&pmf=1&pf=1&zoom=3&rect=-134340820,16594081,-56469727,54952386&p=1&sort=globalrelevanceex&search=maplist&disp=1&listright=true&isMapSearch=true&zoom=3"
response = requests.get(page) # request the json file
json_response =  json.loads(response.text) # parse the json file
soup = Soup(json_response['list']['listHTML'], 'html.parser')
```

and the soup has what you are looking for. If you explore the json, you will find a lot of useful information.
The list of all the URLs can be find with

```
links = [i.attrs['href'] for i in soup.findAll("a",{"class":"hdp-link"})]
```

All the URLs appears twice. If you want that they are unique, you can fix the list, or, otherwise, look for `"hdp-link routable"` in class above. 
But, I always prefer more then less!

Comment: I need to check the answer and will accept it soon as possible.

Comment: I only get few URLs than that 391k after running the script. I accepted your answer, but, I hope you will solve this issue.

Comment: I also get `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` for the line `json_response =  json.loads(response.text)` in the code. However, this is a valid JSON I checked.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.Could you post the json somewhere? Regarding the bulk download of the whole website, you have to find a way to go through all the pages. A possibility is to find where the URL of the json file is called when you switch to page 2. In this way you could iterate the process page by page. Notice that some websites does not provide the whole database with a single query.

Comment: I suggest you provide me a way of how to iterate over all the pages of the website from the URL we get from the NETWORK tab. The other issue is fixed and we can leave it.

Comment: @DdD Unfortunately not anymore (http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/KY/fore_lt/24_rid/2-_beds/globalrelevanceex_sort/38.23818,-78.739014,37.370157,-92.801514_rect/5_zm/)